# How to generate Android Typescript.d.ts files

Tags: android, plugins, typescript, nativescript, typescript-typings

This great article [NativeScript: iOS Tip - See the Metadata & .d.ts files generated for your Cocoapod Plugin](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=227) explains how to generate Typescript .d.ts files for Cocoapods.

I quite frequently use [tns-core-modules/android17.d.ts](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/android17.d.ts) as a reference when developing plugins for Android.

I've read all the docs on the [android-runtime](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime) and could not find anything in regards to generating Typescript .d.ts for imported Android libraries.

> Is there a way to run `TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/tsc" tns build  android` for Android which will generate Typescript .d.ts files?

Or maybe a way to generate another massive `android17.d.ts` file which would include the imported libraries through gradle?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to download and use: https://github.com/NativeScript/android-dts-generator

The android-dts-generator will generate the TS metadata for any `.jar` file you have.
Command line would be: `java -jar build/libs/dts-generator.jar -input <jar1> <jar2> ...`

If you have an `.aar` then you will need to extract the `classes.jar` from inside the `.aar` out, and then run the dts generator on the jar file you extracted.

Comment: Can u help me on this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript